# Why am i getting a result for the components of my return values as opposed to the complete set of return values

Tags: python

Hi all (my first post :) )
Why am getting different results for the individual components of function results as opposed to the set of them?

```
import random


def test():
    di1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    di2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    diTotal = di1+di2

    return diTotal, di1, di2


print(test()[0], test()[1], test()[2], test())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call your function, two new random numbers are produced. You call the test function 4 times in `print(test()[0], test()[1], test()[2], test())`. So, 4 pairs of random numbers are produced, and they are different.

If you call the test function just once, you'll have the same result:

```
import random

def test():
    di1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    di2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    diTotal = di1+di2

    return diTotal, di1, di2

test_output = test()
print(test_output[0], test_output[1], test_output[2], test_output)
```

The output:

```
(3, 1, 2, (3, 1, 2))
```